# How instal Device usb wirelles mediatek - MT7601u RALINK on Ubuntu 20?

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, usb, ralink

I'm new in the linux world.

I'm just installed Ubuntu 20 to try and everything is fine, except by mt7601u wireless device. Ubuntu didn't recognize it at installation. It works fine in Windows 10 and 7.

How can I fix that? If possible in a easy way, because i am not a expert in linux.

lsusb showed me:

```
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp. MT7601U Wireless Adapter
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 045e:0745 Microsoft Corp. Nano Transceiver v1.0 for Bluetooth
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Correct version is Ubuntu 20.04

dmesg | grep mt76 
showed me

```
76.543626] mt7601u 1-6:1.0: ASIC revision: 76010001 MAC revision: 76010500
[ 1176.546995] mt7601u 1-6:1.0: Firmware Version: 0.1.00 Build: 7640 Build time: 201302052146____
[ 1176.996065] mt7601u 1-6:1.0: EEPROM ver:0d fae:00
[ 1177.201994] mt7601u 1-6:1.0: Error: MCU resp urb failed:-71
[ 1177.202003] mt7601u 1-6:1.0: Error: MCU resp evt:0 seq:4-3!
[ 1177.211833] mt7601u 1-6:1.0: Error: MCU resp urb failed:-71
[ 1177.211842] mt7601u 1-6:1.0: Error: MCU resp evt:0 seq:4-3!
[ 1177.221522] mt7601u 1-6:1.0: Error: MCU resp urb failed:-71
[ 1177.221531] mt7601u 1-6:1.0: Error: MCU resp evt:0 seq:4-3!
[ 1177.231135] mt7601u 1-6:1.0: Error: MCU resp urb failed:-71
[ 1177.231144] mt7601u 1-6:1.0: Error: MCU resp evt:0 seq:4-3!
[ 1177.240492] mt7601u 1-6:1.0: Error: MCU resp urb failed:-71
[ 1177.240499] mt7601u 1-6:1.0: Error: MCU resp evt:0 seq:4-3!
[ 1177.240503] mt7601u 1-6:1.0: Error: mt7601u_mcu_wait_resp timed out
[ 1177.587319] mt7601u 1-6:1.0: Vendor request req:07 off:0080 failed:-71
[ 1177.867341] mt7601u 1-6:1.0: Vendor request req:02 off:0080 failed:-71
[ 1178.143324] mt7601u 1-6:1.0: Vendor request req:02 off:0080 failed:-71
[ 1178.143378] mt7601u: probe of 1-6:1.0 failed with error -110
[ 1178.879648] mt7601u 1-6:1.0: ASIC revision: 76010001 MAC revision: 76010500
[ 1178.883079] mt7601u 1-6:1.0: Firmware Version: 0.1.00 Build: 7640 Build time: 201302052146____
```

The commands suggested were executed without fail, however still not showing wifi, only wired network. I also tried on linux mint 19.3, with version 5.3 and also does not show wifi. The system reports show the device:

Network:
Device-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet vendor: ASUSTeK 
           driver: r8169 v: kernel port: d800 bus ID: 02:00.0 chip ID: 10ec:8168 
           IF: enp2s0 state: down mac:

Device-2: Ralink MT7601U Wireless Adapter type: USB driver: usb-network bus ID: 2-4:3            chip ID: 148f:7601

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 20.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `dmesg | grep mt76` terminal command.

Comment: What result for `mokutil --sb-state; dkms status`

Answer (score 2):

Secure boot will need too be disabled, check in terminal `mokutil --sb-state`
Then in terminal

```
sudo apt install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/jeremyb31/mt7601u-5.4.git
sudo dkms add ./mt7601u-5.4
sudo dkms install mt7601u/1.0
```

Reboot